# yii2-admin check role of user

Tags: php, yii2, role, yii2-user

I have a role `Creator` and I want to know how can I check whether the logged in user has `Creator` assigned to them.

I created a function in my `User` class as:

```
public function getIsCreator(){
     $role = Yii::$app->authManager->getRole('Creator')->name;
     $rolesById = Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($this->id);

     return in_array($role, $rolesById);
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Because the above code doesn't validates as expected.

Comment: `var_dump` your values and see what you have there, isn't it obvious?

Comment: Tried it. Nothing comes up.

Comment: How are you using this? People sometimes mistake the User identity with the User model.

Comment: Also if this is related to the other question you are better off doing it like I answered or by using filters

Comment: please say to me :do you use the yii2 basic or yii2 advanced?
if you answer this question i can give you better answer.

Comment: @moeinkh I use my own template. I neither use basic nor advanced templates

Comment: you should know for using authManager library for creating role you should use the "advanced yii2" because in yii2 advanced you have a ready table that save and insert your role automatically if you want i can say how add role and how to use this role on your controller page n "advanced yii2" best regards

Answer (score 1):

To check has user a given role or not you can use this function:

```
public function hasRole($roleName, $userId) {
    $authManager = \Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
    return $authManager->getAssignment($roleName, $userId) ? true : false;
}
```